# Javascript for finding out the value of text in a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, events, cakephp-3.0

I have an edit page in my cakephp-3.0 application, The values in the text boxes are loading from the database.

I want to raise an event and show an `alert` if the value in any of the text boxes is changed from their current value. For example, suppose the value is `"abc"`. An `alert` should be shown if it's changed to `"abcde"`. An `alert` will not shown value is still `"abc"`.

Currently I am using this however it will call the function I clicked on the text box itself:

```
<input size="10" type="text" value="13-12-1899" onchange="checkChange()" style="border:1px solid #fff;">
```

Comment: `But this will call the function I clicked on the text box itself` Not true - it's called when the input loses focus. As such, the code you have now should work exactly as you describe your requirements

Comment: where is the definition for checkChange() ?

Comment: I don't get the issue 100%. Do you want to get the alert instantly after changing the input ? If yes, then your code should be ok.  Or you have something like a submit button, and you want to get all the alerts for every input ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to catch changes AS THEY HAPPEN rather than when the input loses focus, try this:

```js
$("#checkme").on("input", function(){
  var myVal = $(this).val();
  console.log("changed to "+myVal+"!");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="abc" id="checkme"  >
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input size="10" type="text" value="13-12-1899" onchange="checkChange()" style="border:1px solid #fff;">
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkChange(e){
        var oldVal = e.getAttribute('value');
        var nwVal = e.value;
        if(oldVal!=nwVal)
            alert("the value \""+oldVal+"\" have been changed to \""+nwVal+"\"");
    }
</script>
```